# multiple instaces of Dynamic modalpopupextender

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have modalpopupextender in user control. And I load user control dynamic and multiple instance of that user control meaning I have multiple instances of modalpopupextender loaded dynamically. How do I set behaviorid so I can call .add_shown method to call some javascript on modal popup load ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

function pageLoad() {

```
//Find all the Popups that deal with ZoomTo and add a add_shown handler.
var AllThem = Sys.Application.getComponents();

for (them in AllThem) {
    if (AllThem[them]._PopupControlID != undefined) {
        var d = AllThem[them]._PopupControlID;
        if (d.indexOf("ZoomToPanel") >= 0) {
            //Add the
            AllThem[them].add_shown(onZoomToPanelShown);
        }
    }
}
}


function onZoomToPanelShown() {
   //Clear the AutoComplete box.
   var t2 = $$get('txtAutoComplete');
   t2.value = "";
}
```